# Logs from Airflow DAGs not written to GCP Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

In our Airflow DAG code, we are trying to write the airflow logs directly into stack-driver using the sample code present in:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#log-entries

However, as per default setting the logs get written to the logs directory in the Airflow GCE VM. We changed the `airflow.cfg` file to include the below entries(https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/logging/stackdriver.html):

```
remote_logging = True
remote_base_log_folder = stackdriver://airflow-task-logs
google_key_path = <path in the vm to the json file>
```

But still we are not able to see the logs in the cloud logging/stackdriver when we filter by the log name 'airflow-task-logs'.

What extra configuration is required to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of [how the value for `remote_base_log_folder` is parsed](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.3.3/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py#L241), you need to provide it as an absolute path.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urlparse("stackdriver://airflow-task-logs").path[1:]
# evaluates to  ''

urlparse("stackdriver:///airflow-task-logs").path[1:]
# evaluates to airflow-task-logs
```

Set `remote_base_log_folder`

```py
remote_base_log_folder = 'stackdriver:///airflow-task-logs'
```